# register transfer

Tags: rtl

I am trying to understand RTL(Register-Transfer level) systems and in particular the implementation of the control subsystem by means of sequential execution graphs. I don't understand how to implement a construct like this:

> if x>=x_ref
>
> (do something)
>
> else
>
> (do something else)
>
> end

I think that I should include a comparator inside the ALU. However, it is not clear how should I manage the result of the comparator in order to jump to another state.

Since, if we use implicit sequencing, control instructions and branch instructions are intrinsically different, how can I use the result of a control instruction (i.e. of the output of the comparator) to assign the successor state?
I tried searching on the Internet and on my textbook(Introduction to digital systems, Ercegovac Lang Moreno), but so far I have not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly how you implement it depends on the performance you need, which determines how deeply you pipeline it.

I am going to assume that `(do something)` and `(do something else)` take approximately as long as the comparison `x>=x_ref`, and that the system is clocked slow enough that there is enough additional time to propagate signals through a multiplexer before the next clock. (I'm also assuming all of `x, x_ref,` and the inputs to `do_something_*` are synchronous to the clock signal, and that you have a basic understanding of [VHDL signal assignment semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532))

Then the initial implementation

```
process(clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if x>=x_ref then
       Result <= (do something);
    else
       Result <= (do something else)
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

is equivalent to the following, all evaluated in parallel (i.e. outside a process)

```
Test <= x >= xref;   -- Test is a boolean signal
A <= (do something);
B <= (do something else);
A_or_B <= A when Test else B;
Result <= A_or_B when rising_edge(clk);
```

In other words, both arms of the IF, as well as the comparison are evaluated in parallel. Then their outputs `A,B` ripple through the selector (multiplexer) onto `A_or_B` - which operates in parallel to the above, but whose output is invalid until all of A, B and Test are stable.

Also operating in parallel is a clocked register, which waits until the next clock edge and latches its input onto `Result`. This is just shorthand for the normal clocked process :

```
process(clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    Result <= A_or_B;
  end if;
end process;
```

If you have followed this explanation, you have just seen an entire IF statement execute in a single clock cycle.

The actual basic blocks may look a little like assembly language compiled from the above code, but remember each is a little block of hardware, operating in parallel, instead of sequentially executed assembler instructions.

---

The advantage of the `IF` form in a clocked process is that it makes the high level operation relatively clear and easy to follow. If you can follow the logic through all those parallel assignments more easily then your mind works differently to mine!

Both forms should synthesise down to the same hardware, assuming the synthesis tool recognises the `when rising_edge(clk)` syntax. If it doesn't, just use the equivalent clocked process.

And all else being equal, the higher level form, which is easier to read, understand and maintain, is to be preferred.

---

Now let's assume it's not fast enough, but `(do something)`, `(do something else)` and `x>=x_ref` each take less than a clock cycle. We can pipeline this more deeply by performing these operations in a single cycle (in parallel) then performing the selection (the actual `if`) in a second cycle.

```
Test <= x >= xref when rising_edge(clk);   -- insert a register
A <= (do something) when rising_edge(clk); -- ditto
B <= (do something else) when rising_edge(clk); -- ditto
A_or_B <= A when Test else B;
Result <= A_or_B when rising_edge(clk); -- second stage pipeline register
```

If you're wondering why `A_or_B` DOESN'T have its own pipeline register ... good question. The answer is that it could: we would write the last 2 lines as a single line :

```
Result <= (A when Test else B) when rising_edge(clk);
```

Or equally I could have separated the operation from the register in the earlier cases:

```
A_int <= (do something);
A <= A_int when rising_edge(clk);
```

---

This leaves one remaining question : can we maintain the clarity of the high level operation while pipelining it more deeply? Well, here's my approach...

```
Process(clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    -- Pipeline stage 1
    Test <= x >= x_ref;
    A    <= (do something);
    B    <= (do something else);
    -- Pipeline stage 2
    if Test then
       Result <= A;
    else
       Result <= B;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: "Then their outputs A,B ripple through the selector (multiplexer) onto A_or_B."                                                                            If I am not mistaken, this means that the control signal of the selector is the boolean value (x>=xref). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, - its value is `x >=xref` and I named it `Test`.